# Can IntelliTrace log be used to inspect value of a complex type

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, intellitrace

Let's say I have a class A that contains a class B which itself contains another class C. Something as follows

```
class A
{
  B  b;
}

class B
{
  C  c;
}
```

I have a method that takes instance of class A as parameter.

```
private void MyMethod(A a)
{

}
```

Let's say this class A instance passed in this method contains some data that is causing some issue and I need to figure that out. Will I be able to inspect value of A instance and any of its children if I capture IntelliTrace log?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default it is not possible because of two limitations of IntelliTrace i.e.:

- IntelliTrace records/captures only values of fields/properties that
  that are primitive data types.
- IntelliTrace does not analyse the object graph.

Let's extend your example:

```
public class A
{
   public int Prop1 { get; set; }
   public C Prop2  { get; set; }
}
```

In this case in IntelliTrace log you will only find a value of `Prop1` because it is an int. In the case of `Prop2` you will only see if it is set or not.

As the workaround you can try to define a custom diagnostic event. However, it is not so easy. You can start by reading [Custom TraceSource and debugging using IntelliTrace](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2014/12/16/custom-tracesource-and-debugging-using-intellitrace/) and [VS 2010 : Customize IntelliTrace events](http://blog.qetza.net/en/2010/03/08/vs-2010-customize-intellitrace-events/). See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39128665/intellitrace-arguments-by-reference) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39128665/intellitrace-arguments-by-reference) question.